# products id in export sheet does not match with magento back end ids against their products name

Tags: magento-2.2.5

i want to export my products from magento back end with products ids as when we export csv of products ids should be matched in csv and back end against their products name but when i export sheet and search with id in sheet different product get as save in magento back end

my magento back end products id

[image]

my export sheet products sheet in which on same id product name does not match

[image]

Comment: Not getting exactly. Can you please give example. what you actually facing the issue

Comment: my magento back end products id's matched with db products id's but when i search ed one id of back end product in csv export sheet same product name not come against its id

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Got my point

Comment: Are you exporting product from system->Export->Product?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra yes but id's getting from db table

Comment: Means? Are you running any custom query in Db to get id's?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra yes simple sql query run to get id's from table catalog_product_entity

Comment: Can you please add that query in question

Comment: select * from juliancharles.catalog_product_entity; i am using workbench